# How is a student directory best handled in WordPress?

Tags: directory

I am doing a WordPress site for a school. One of the pages would have a list of 20 or so students, which would include their name, photo and small blurb.

How is this type of thing handled in Wordpress? I would like the user of the CMS to be able to manage this page effectively - adding/removing students etc.

I know Wordpress is being used in e-commerce sites, so people who run these site must be in the same situation on their pages of products.

Should I be using plugins?   Custom fields?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) 'student', with [post thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) for the images. The post title would be their name, post content would be the blurb. If the code scares you, there are [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) to assist.

[Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies) are also available to you, which operate like categories and tags, but can be any set of attributes or means of grouping.

Comment: Hi Milo thanks for the reply, with regards to the custom post type solution... are you suggesting that each list item (i.e student) would be an individual post in WP, THEN, I would pull all those posts into on Page?

Comment: @Jared- yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go for something which is more obvious. Students as users, and store their info in usermeta.

Any user plugin or user related code will help you in managing users.

Comment: This would be the preferred method *if* you actually wanted to allow the students themselves to login (and possibly modify their usermeta). If the desire, however, is to have the owner handle all the content, however, I wouldn't recommend this method.

Also, while extending usermeta is possible, it's a bit more difficult and far less open to customization that is the custom post type method...

Comment: @somatic As per my way, it will keep the possibility of providing them accounts at a later date in future and having them on the site doesn't mean you have to use the login functionality. Why did you say usermeta is difficult when a custom post type will use postmeta. There is not much difference in terms of efforts.

That said, they can restrict the login, and even if allowed, then can restrict them to edit their meta. It makes more sense semantically and as a bonus, a lot of other plugins for users can be used.

Comment: In the context of a "controlled directory", semantically, one could argue it makes more sense to keep the "users" as only those who are allowed to login and manage the site (staff, editors, web admins, etc). This makes even more sense if the site is delivering content other than just the student listings (like a blog/news). The "student" (custom post type) is just a generic item (like the e-commerce analogy, as products).

Comment: As for customizing the user profile page vs. a custom post type, it's simply my experience that it's both easier and better documented. The user profile page and the usermeta itself is just not as flexible...

Comment: I believe it just boils down to personal preferences.